# Enforce non-void returning methods to always assign to a variable or discard

Tags: c#, resharper

Often I have the pieces of code that look like this:

```cs
        private void OnChangeLanguageCommandExecuted(object obj)
        {
            pLngService.ChangeLanguage(newLcid);
        }
```

In this case the `ChangeLanguage(...)` method returns a value, although that value (true for success, false for non-success) is not used. The problem is, I had no clue when looking at the code that this method was returning a value.

I did not write the method, nor have I control over it.

Therefore i'd like to globally enforce a policy where:

Each non-void returning method must be assigned a variable, e.g.
`var unused = pLngService.ChangeLanguage(newLcid);`

Or the discard operator should be used, to make it more explicit:
`_ = pLngService.ChangeLanguage(newLcid);`

I'm of course open to other suggestions, the main goal here is to make it more verbose that both a method is returning a value and that i'm choosing to discard it.

I was hoping there'd be a rule for visual studio or Resharper where i could enfore this policy by generating compiler warnings. I won't like to make this a compiler error, that seems to rigorous. I did some quick looking around but i did not find anything oob but i feel like im overlooking something.

I'm using projects in vs2017 (net4) and vs2019 (net8/netcore3.0) so something that would work in either of those setups would be great.

EDIT:
I found out, literally whilst writing a roslyn code analyzer, that apperently you can configure this with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0058

The code fixes were exactly what I was looking for:

```cs
// Original code:
System.Convert.ToInt32("35");

// After code fix for IDE0058:

// csharp_style_unused_value_expression_statement_preference = discard_variable
_ = System.Convert.ToInt32("35");

// csharp_style_unused_value_expression_statement_preference = unused_local_variable
var unused = Convert.ToInt32("35");
```

There is the following rule:

> csharp_style_unused_value_expression_statement_preference

With options:

> Option values     discard_variable - Prefer to assign an unused expression to a discard

> unused_local_variable - Prefer to assign an unused expression to a local variable that is never used

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/432

Comment: What problem are you solving by enforcing such a rule? Easier codereview? Something else? I personally don't see a problem, if return value is ignored. That's how C# works since 2002.

Comment: Really, the name `ChangeLanguage` implies that the method should throw an exception if it fails to change the language. Then ignoring the error becomes obvious, because you'll have a `try` with an empty `catch`.

Comment: @Sinatr readbility, this is not code i've written, im looking over it and there was an issue with this particular method. Apperently, it returns a bool succes/no success, which aided me a lot in solving the issue.

Comment: @canton7 Interesting thread, thanks. About the name of the method, once again, it is not under my control, so i wholeheartedly agree, tbh the whole framework im using is full of badly named methods, but i cannot change this. which is why i'd like a policy like i was talking about...

Comment: Yeah, a Roslyn analyzer is the way to go here. I couldn't find an off-the-shelf one however, just the request I linked above

Comment: Can't you add [MustUseReturnValueAttribute](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#MustUseReturnValueAttribute)?

Comment: @Sinatr I hadn't seen that attribute yet, a good suggestion. However i still have no control over a lot of methods i'm calling (they're in a different, obfuscated dll), so no luck there.

Comment: @canton7 I'm also not seeing any roslyn analyzers available. They seem easy enough to write however so perhaps ill take this on as a weekend project if i have the time. There are already analyzers to avoid Async void methods, so it should be easy to adapt from there, e.g. https://github.com/TheAlmightyBob/AsyncVoidAnalyzer/blob/master/AsyncVoidAnalyzer/AsyncVoidAnalyzer/DiagnosticAnalyzer.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers, please refer to the code rule IDE0058:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0058
Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options?view=vs-2019 on how to configure editor rules.

Which should provide what you need. If thats not available, or the rule is buggy in your particular version of VS you can also take a look at this quick roslyn analyzer i made on a saturday morning:

https://github.com/sommmen/DiscardReturnValueAnalyzer/tree/master

She works but there are still some things i'm not happy with, like the actual analysis messages. But since IDE0059 should already cover this use case I'm not putting more effort into this. If you need this for some reason, feel free to create an issue and I might take a look.

Also the repo is not published or something so you'd have to clone and build it yourself.

P.s. Roslyn analyzers are pretty dope once you get the hang of them.